# Найти минимальное число объектов n из которых можно составить C сочетаний по k

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Как найти минимальное число объектов n из которых можно составить C сочетаний по k?

Comment: В смысле вы формулу ищете или программный алгоритм?

Comment: Если прологарифмировать уравнение получаются симпатичные неравенства ограничивающие диапазон `n`. Внутри диапазона можно отыскать решение двоичным поиском с формулой Стирлинга. Полученное приближенное решение проверить и уточнить на настоящих факториалах.

Comment: @wh4y В связи с разночтением? будьте добры, приведите **точное** условие задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**первый вариант**

тупой перебор от k и до обеда:

```
import math

k = 100
с = 90548514656103281165404177077484163874504589675413336841320

n = k
while True:
    if math.comb(n, k) == с:
        break
    n += 1

print(n)
```

в принципе условно быстро работает до некоторых больших чисел

**второй вариант**

```
C(n, k) = n! / (n! / (n - k)!)
```

откуда

```
n! / (n - k)! = C(n, k) * k!
```

или

```
(n - k + 1) *  (n - k + 2) * ... * (n - 1) / n = C(n, k) * k!
```

Эту запись можно представить как уравнение `x` k-ой степени:

```
(x - k + 1) *  (x - k + 2) * ... * (x - 1) / n = C(n, k) * k!
```

Дальше остаётся только решить ПРИБЛИЖЁННО данное уравнение, после чего перебором проверить `n` в диапазоне от `[x - 1; x + 1]`

Например можно градиентный спуск помучить

Недостаток - может поехать точность вычислений с плавающей запятой при решении уравнения сверхвысоких степеней

Comment: `math.comb` есть начиная с `3.8`, в Google Colab её нет, эх

Comment: ничего не мешает написать ее самому - там же весь смысл, что не надо вычислять факториалы, а вычисляем оставшуюся часть после сокращения

Answer (score 1):

Давайте я сформулирую задачу более строго. Итак, имеем некоторое значение С, и вопрос ставится так — в какой самой верхней строке треугольника Паскаля встретится это число?

Т.е. нужно найти пару (n,k), для которой число сочетаний из n по k равно C, при этом накладывается условие, чтобы `n` было минимально.

Я верно понял условие задачи? потому что все написанное далее — для нее.

Вопросов два.

1. Насколько *точно* должна быть решена задача, и
2. в каком диапазоне значений.

Теоретически у *такой* задачи (как ее сформулировал я) решение есть всегда, просто хотя бы потому, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это — `n==C` — верхняя граница решения. Нижнюю границу можно оценить, используя формулу Стирлинга, исходя из того, что максимальное число сочетаний при фиксированном `n` достигается при `n=2k`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе, решение относительно *n* записывается через функцию Ламберта, но это по сути для аналитического решения ничего не дает. Но это уравнение легко решается численно.

А дальше все зависит от пунктов 1 и 2. Если нужно *точное* решение — то по сути не остается ничего, кроме как перебирать возможные варианты от минимального `n`, полученного из решения уравнения, и до `n == C`. Определенную роль может сыграть информация о числе C — например, если оно простое, то, если я не ошибаюсь, ничего не остается, кроме как `n==C`. Или если оно, например, имеет вид `p(p-1)/2` при простом `p`...

Небольшая оптимизация перебора состоит в том, что считать все `k` не нужно, можно идти от 1 до момента, когда число сочетаний превысит заданное значение, и, кроме того, можно легко и просто получать значение числа сочетаний из предыдущего:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что считать страшные факториалы или просто разные значения сочетаний совершенно не нужно, что существенно ускорит вычисления.

Еще — самые лучшие методы могут считать сочетания с использованием встроенного 64-битного значения `unsigned long long` только до 64 (имею в виду максимальное значение сочетания), так что при таких `C` достаточно простого перебора. Б*о*льшие числа будут требовать длинной арифметики и очень большого времени...

Если же точное решение не требуется (а мне кажется, что это именно так), а нужна *оценка* такого *минимального* значения `n` — то решайте численно показанное выше уравнение (кстати, оно отлично решается методом простых итераций).

Comment: Я думаю что `k` тоже задано. Мы движемся вдоль стороны треугольника Паскаля, числа растут, и тут раз - и решение.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Тогда как минимум нет никакой гарантии существования решения.